# Android - Disable swipe to previous screen

Tags: android, android-gesture, android-swipe

How to intercept the swipe to left movement to navigate to previous screen and disable the navigation ?

I have tried to intercept the action and return `false` but it does not work:

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    view.setOnTouchListener{ v, event ->
        Timber.d("~ TouchEvent: ${event.toString()}")
        when(event.action){
            ACTION_DOWN -> {
                false
            }

            ACTION_MOVE -> {
                false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to disable the *swipe to previous screen* gesture ?

reference: [Detect common gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector#detect-a-subset-of-supported-gestures)

Comment: Since you didn't get a good answer, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61149117/android-10-gesture-navigation-disable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set new callback for `on back pressed` case. And with new callback, you can disable all the actions and do nothing.

Thus, app won't navigate to previous screen when clicked on back button or when used swipe to left gesture.

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback { }
}
```

Comment: This disables _all_ methods of going back, not just the swipe gesture...